# Как узнать размер файла

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

В общем есть статичная страница на VUE. На ней отображаю список файлов. По клику по ним они скачиваются. Мне нужно отобразить размер каждого файла. Есть ли какой нибудь способ html или js который мог бы узнать размер файла? Повторяю что документы не загружаю ни куда. Просто по внутреннему url отображаю на странице. К примеру так:

```
<a class="downloadMe" href="/files/me.docx" download title="Тут например отобразить размер этого файла">
```

гугл че-то не знает вариантов

Comment: «статичная» и «на VUE» это взаимоисключающие вещи. А узнать размер файла на стороне браузера можно только запустив скачивание файла (а в особо запущенных случаях размер станет известен только после завершения скачивания)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашел я решение сам. Есть у меня массив с url файлов и с их именами, так вот при каждом цикле for я вызываю метод в котором создаю файл blob на js(естественно не пальцем же) и при создании передаю в него url файла, что в последующем дает мне размер и тип файла. Все просто. Понимаю что задача странная. Но система работает. Кусочек кода чуть позже допишу сюда...

Comment: Это и есть скачивание файла. По сути, вы заставляете клиентов автоматически скачивать файлы, которые они не хотели скачивать, и впустую тратите их интернет-трафик

Comment: @andreymal А есть варианты? Как сделать чтобы отображался размер файлов?   Да даже если бы из бэка доставал массив с url адресами файлов, я бы всеравно получил от сервера лишь json строку. Она бы ни че делала.

Comment: Заранее посмотреть на бэкенде размеры файлов и отдать браузеру готовые циферки. Если этот бэкенд вообще есть, конечно

Comment: @andreymal вот к примеру у тебя есть список из 10 url файлов. Просто 10 url.  Файлы сами лежат на сервере твоем. Как ты на бэке узнаешь их размер? Как ты узнаешь размер каждого файла по url, вставишь эти все значения в массив и вернешь клиенту на фронт форматом json? Я не спорю что это можно будет как-то вычислить, просто как это можно сделать? Как бы ты это сделал?

Comment: Просто написал бы код, проходящийся циклом по списку файлов и вызывающий [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsstatpath-options-callback) (или его аналог в других ЯП) для узнавания размера, да и всё. Что-то не так?

Comment: @andreymal всё так. Спасибо. Полюбому на php есть аналог.  Просто думал есть ли способ менее ресурснозатратный. Типо что-то подобное: size("/files/myFile.txt"); А так получается нужно получить файл а потом считывать то что тебе нужно о нём. А если файлы были бы очень большими(пару гигов один файл) и массово бы делались запросы то серверу пришлось бы не легко). Но за мысль спасибо 

Answer (score 0):

В комментарии уже ответили, что никак

Если у вас "статичный" сайт, может вручную обозначите размер тогда? Либо, если у вас есть бэкенд-сторона, отдавать имена файлов, их путь, и заранее размер файла